# Backbone.js fetch() JSON to model get() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, model

Basically I want to fetch a **JSON** file and store it in a model. However, when I try to access the attributes via `get()` it returns undefined. So lets say the JSON file has an array games that consists of objects with some attributes. It doesn't really matter. Just want to save them in the model and access them. So I'm doing something like this.

```
var player = Backbone.Model.extend({
   initialize: function(app, options) {
      this.app = app;
      var _this = this;

      this.fetch({
         url: "someurl",
         success: function() {
            console.log("success");
         }
      });
   }
});

var instplayer = new player();
instplayer.on('change', function(){
   console.log(model);
   console.log(model.get(games));
})
```

So I figured that I need an event to ensure that `get()` is called when the data is really available. But this still returns undefined. What do I need to do?

Comment: Do you mean that you fetch a player, and there's multidimentional data, that contains games? Is it like this:  
`{ username: "joe",  games: [ { title:"Game One" }, { title: "Game Two" }  ]  }`  
and then you just want to access the `games` property, is that right?

Comment: Yes that is right. As long as I can get anything that has been fetched from the JSON data. I mean I see the data when I look at the object through console.log but get() just simply returns undefined. Of course some values I put on the model with the defaults options can be returned without any problems.

Comment: After making sure you pass a string to the `.get` method, like `model.get("games")` in quotes, I would also suggest to use `sync` event instead of `change`. `sync` will make sure to fire when the content has come from the server. `change` will fire on any change to that model data, which might be more often than you'd want.

Comment: Thanks thats it. Makes sense so `change` was fired before the data was fully loaded and that why I couldn't get() it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great! I've also added a working example in my answer below, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I imagined you have a json for your player like this (I've mocked it [here](http://www.mocky.io/v2/56261127250000a01accb34f) for the example below to work):

```
{
    "username": "joe",
    "games": [
        {
            "title": "Pacman"
        }, {
            "title": "Super Mario" } 
    ]
}
```

And here's a complete working example of how I would deal with managing and rendering this kind of data:

```js
var Game = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    title: ''
  }
});

var Games = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Game
});

var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    username: ''
  },
  url: 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/56261127250000a01accb34f',
  initialize: function(){
    this.games = new Games();
    this.listenTo( this, "sync", this.initGames );
    this.fetch();
  },
  initGames: function(){
    this.games.add( this.get('games') );
    this.trigger('ready', this);
  }
});

var PlayerView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template('<h1><%=username%></h1> and his games: <ol class="games"></ol>'),
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
    this.model.games.each( this.renderGame, this );
    return this;
  },
  renderGame: function(game, i){
    var gameView = new GameView({ model: game });
    gameView.render().$el.appendTo( this.$('.games') );
  }
});

var GameView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  template: _.template('<strong>Game:</strong> <%=title%>'),
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ));
    return this;
  }
});


var dude = new Player();
dude.on('ready', function(player){
  var playerView = new PlayerView({ model: player });
  playerView.render().$el.appendTo( document.body );
});
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js'></script>
```

Comment: Awesome. Much appreciated. That is exactly what I need. Pretty genius to add a collection to a model. Didn't know that that this is even possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a typo or not but you are not passing `model` to the `callback`

```
instplayer.on('change', function(){
  console.log(model);
  console.log(model.get(games));
})
```

it should be

```
instplayer.on('change', function(model, options){
  console.log(model);
  console.log(model.get("games"));
})
```

then `games` must be a `string` not a `variable`.

Another thing I suggest you to be aware of is what the `json` returns; sometimes you have to override the `parse` function to get the exact results.

Again if your fetching an `array` and not a single object, maybe you should use a `collection` of `players`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes that is indeed a typo. Your suggestions aside this code then should give me the array back? I tried the same with a collection and then simply did `parse: function(response) { return response.games; }` This also populates the collection but I somehow cant access the populated attributes.

Comment: did you assign a `model` to the `collection`?